# The P-Value and significance level I added to R ggplot, are incorrectly placed

Tags: ggpubr, significance

I tried to add significane level (package:ggpubrto)to my t_test plot (package:rstatix) and got a plot which the lines of significance are in the "pulled" to the right of the plot.
I copy the code from this link [https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-perform-multiple-t-test-in-r-for-different-variables/][1] but still got the same plot
here is the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
library(ggpubr)
```

```
  # Prepare the data and inspect a random sample of the data
   mydata <- iris %>%
   filter(Species != "setosa") %>%
   as_tibble()
   mydata %>% sample_n(6)
```

```
mydata.long <- mydata %>%
   pivot_longer(-Species, names_to = "variables", values_to = "value")
   mydata.long %>% sample_n(6)
```

```
   stat.test <- mydata.long %>%
   group_by(variables) %>%
   t_test(value ~ Species) %>%
   adjust_pvalue(method = "BH") %>%
   add_significance()
   stat.test
```

```
   myplot <- ggboxplot(
    mydata.long, x = "Species", y = "value",
    fill = "Species", palette = "npg", legend = "none",
    ggtheme = theme_pubr(border = TRUE)) +
    facet_wrap(~variables)
    # Add statistical test p-values
    stat.test <- stat.test %>% add_xy_position(x = "Species")
    myplot + stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p.adj.signif")`
```

[this is the result from the site:][2]

[and this is what i got:][4]

any idea what i did wrong?

My Rstudio version is  1.4.1103
[1]: https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-perform-multiple-t-test-in-r-for-different-variables/
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzPo6.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rtAO.jpg
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJolk.png

Answer (score 1):

I found it
i changed the "xmin" and "xmax values of "stat.test